# Is there any way to skip the tutorial?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I played the KoA demo, so I pretty much already understand the buttons and the basic lore of the game.  However, the game seems intent on making me jump through all these hoops and teaching me all of this again (spoiler alert: *You find a sword!*).

I imagine if I want to start the game over again with a different character, I'm going to have to go through all of this *yet again.*  I tend to want to restart about a couple of hours in, once I have a clear idea about the skill trees and the various perks.

Is there some way to skip this "tutorial phase" or speed up the process?

Comment: The demo detected when you completed the well of souls, and let you skip it. I'd be surprised if the main game didn't. But that said, they *are* separate programs, and probably aren't looking at each other's data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you've played the demo, you can't skip the tutorial section of the main game.

However, as @Raven said in the comments, the demo did let you skip the tutorial if you play it for a second time so I imagine that the same is true for the main game.

I played the demo twice, and skipped the tutorial the second time through. I recall only having minimal items in my inventory after skipping the tutorial (one set of armor for each of might, finesse, and sorcery) and a few weapons. You probably get more loot playing through it, which you can sell for gold once you get to the first town. More gold is never a bad thing. :)

Comment: One thing I'll add is that I did discover I could skip the cutscenes - on the Xbox this was "start" and then "X" - this sped things up at least a tad.